# draw line with shift operation

Tags: tikz-pgf, shift

I would like draw line above two node relatively, I try below code but the yshift looks like werid.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
 \node[draw] (A) {B};
 \node[draw,right=of A] (B) {B};

 \def\dy{1cm}
 \draw[draw] ([yshift=\dy]A) -- ([yshift=\dy]B) node[pos=.5] {Hello};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output
[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but are you maybe looking for `\draw[draw] (A.north east) -- (B.north west) node[pos=.5] {Hello};`?

Comment: Note that you nest two `tikzpicture`s in your MWE. In order to make `yshift` behave as (possibly) expected in such cases, you need to give a coordinate such as `0,0` or an anchor such as `A.east`.

Comment: ... or `\draw[draw] (A.north east) -- (B.north west) node[above,pos=.5] {Hello};` if the text should be above the line

Comment: you need to explicit define anchor on node shape from where you like to shift star and end of line.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz or maybe `([yshift=1cm]A.center)` or `([yshift=1cm]A.north)`.

Comment: `tikzpicture`s shouldn't be nested unless you really know what you're doing and, even then, only as a last resort.

Comment: Interesting outcome. Usually, a node name without an anchor (i.e. any `.…` stuff) activated the behavior of TikZ to automatically find a point on the border to connect, too. This is not deactivated when options are used and then mess the calculation up. This is easily fixable in the code but you could also just specify the center (or any other anchor of where the 1cm should be measured): `([yshift=1cm]A.center) -- ([yshift=1cm]B.center)`.